# Getting an error on JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, to-json

I was reading an article by Derick Bailey [Don’t Return A JSON Document From The toJSON Method](http://derickbailey.com/2015/10/26/dont-return-a-json-document-from-the-tojson-method/?__s=m6ajpfq5rzjjaxnoxfr3)

I was trying to convert the following JSON object into Javascript:

```
var userJSON = "{\"firstName\":\"Derick\",\"lastName\":\"Bailey\"}";
var parseOnce = JSON.parse(userJSON.to_json).first;
var userObject = JSON.parse(parseOnce.to_json).first;
```

When I run the code I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"

Here is a jsbin of the same code https://jsbin.com/zugojoyaro/edit?js,console

Comment: `parseOnce.to_json` doesn't exist.

Comment: In trying to fix this I came across this article http://makandracards.com/makandra/15611-how-to-fix-unexpected-token-error-for-json-parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a copy & paste problem from the blog post... (and a small error in the blog post, itself)

```
var userJSON = "{\"firstName\":\"Derick\",\"lastName\":\"Bailey\"}";

var parseOnce = JSON.parse(userJSON);
```

this works... but the code you have:

`var parseOnce = JSON.parse(userJSON.to_json).first;`

includes a `.to_json` and a `.first` attribute that don't exist. it looks like your trying to use ruby code on a JavaScript object